# xslt choose when multiple OR conditions

Tags: xslt

I'm wondering if the below is possible. I want to check if any of these conditions come back as yes to print the statement.

Wondering what is the best way to write this. Thanks

```
<li>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="overdraftmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or businessmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or farmermoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or loanprimiummoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or loanmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or baseloanmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or termloanprimiummoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or termmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or variablemoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected' or fixedloanmoreaffordable/option [@id='yes']='selected'">Statement One</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Statement Two</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</li>
```

or is it better to do seperate when statements even though I just want to determine if any condition is yes print the statement.

Thanks

Addition:

This seems exactly what I need but my code is seperated into alot of if seperate pages so I don't think they can communicate to know if YES was selected in one of the others

```
<xsl:if test="overdraft &gt; 0">
        <div style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
            <br/>
            <b>Overdraft</b><br/>
            An Overdraft allows your current account to go into an overdrawn position up to an agreed limit.<br/>
        </div>

        <xsl:for-each select="overdrafts/overdraftdata">

            <div style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
                <br/>
                This product is suitable because;
                <ul>
                    <li>You are seeking a lending product for the purpose of <xsl:value-of select="overdraftpurpose"/></li>
                    <li>You are seeking a total amount of credit of EUR <xsl:value-of select="overdraftamount"/></li>
                    <li><xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="*[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) - 9) = 'affordable']/option[@id='yes']='selected'">
                                Repayment of the debt has been structured in a manner that is more affordable given your current circumstances
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                You are likely to be able to repay the debt in the manner required under the credit agreement
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </li>
                    <li>It is available for the term you require</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="businesscreditline &gt; 0">

        <div style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
            <br/>
            <b>Business Credit Line</b><br/>
            A Business Credit Line provides you with the convenience and flexibility of a pre-arranged line of 
            credit. It will facilitate improved budgeting and will give you greater choice in meeting your working
            capital and short term funding needs<br/>
        </div>

        <xsl:for-each select="businesscreditlines/businesscreditlinedata">

            <div style="margin-top: 0cm; margin-bottom: 0cm;">
                <br/>
                This product is suitable because;
                <ul>
                    <li>You are seeking a lending product for the purpose of <xsl:value-of select="businesspurpose"/></li>
                    <li>You are seeking a total amount of credit of EUR <xsl:value-of select="businessamount"/></li>
                    <li><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="*[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) - 9) = 'affordable']/option[@id='yes']='selected'">Repayment of the debt has been structured in a manner that is more affordable given your current circumstances</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>You are likely to be able to repay the debt in the manner required under the credit agreement</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></li>
                    <li>It is available for the term you require</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:if>'
```

Comment: I believe I need to get back to the main lending node e.g. I have <xsl:for-each select="overdrafts/overdraftdata"> inside overdraft so obviously it can only see the YES inside this one. Is there a way to overwrite inside the for each to sweep through all nodes in lending?

Comment: ok I'm learning. simple solution for this I put // infront. <xsl:when test="//*[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) - 9) = 'affordable']/option[@id='yes']='selected'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your test was testing all possible child elements, you could simplify it to this

```
 <xsl:when test="*/option[@id='yes']='selected'">Statement One</xsl:when>
```

This will check all child elements off the current element.

If you wanted to be more specific, and only check elements whose name ended in 'affordable' you could do this instead

```
 <xsl:when test="
     *[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) - 9) = 'affordable']
     /option[@id='yes']='selected'">
   Statement One
 </xsl:when>
```

This is assuming XSLT1.0. In XSLT2.0 you would be able to simplify this by using the 'ends-with' function.

```
<xsl:when test="
    *[ends-with(local-name(),'affordable')]/option [@id='yes']='selected'">
  Statement One
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compress it a bit by saying

```
(overdraftmoreaffordable | businessmoreaffordable | farmermoreaffordable |
  loanprimiummoreaffordable | loanmoreaffordable| baseloanmoreaffordable |
  termloanprimiummoreaffordable | termmoreaffordable | variablemoreaffordable |
  fixedloanmoreaffordable)/option[@id='yes']='selected'
```

taking advantage of the fact that an `=` comparison between a node set and a string is true if *any* of the nodes in the node set has a value equal to the given string.  Alternatively, if what you're doing there is enumerating all the possible element names that contain the substring "moreaffordable" then you could get away with

```
*[contains(local-name(), 'moreaffordable')]/option[@id='yes'] = 'selected'
```